# Shiny: cannot delete rows more than 1 time

Tags: javascript, r, datatables, shiny

I am working on a shiny app. The server.R contains codes like......

```
dFt1 <- reactiveValues()
dFt1$dat <- data.frame(loadTransactionData())
...
output$t_tab_1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(
        dFt1$dat
        ,selection = list(mode = "single")
        ,options = list(
            rownames = TRUE
            ,pageLength = 10
            ,order = list(list(2,"desc"),list(1,"asc"))
        )
    )
})
...
observe({
    if (is.null(input$delete) || input$delete == 0){return()}
    session$sendCustomMessage(
        type = 'jsCode'
        ,list(value = 'confirm("Are You Sure?");')
    )
})

observeEvent(input$deleteConfirmChoice, {
    if (input$deleteConfirmChoice == "TRUE") {
        x <- input$t_tab_1_rows_selected
        deleteTransaction(x)
        isolate(dFt1$dat <- dFt1$dat[row.names(dFt1$dat) != x, ])
    }
})  

deleteTransaction <- function(x) {
    qy <- "DELETE FROM Transactions where timestamp = '<t>'"
    qy <- gsub("<t>",x,qy)
    db <- dbConnect(SQLite(), dbname=systemDatabase)
    dbGetQuery(db,qy)
    dbDisconnect(db)
}
```

And of course there is the delete button in the ui.R and a called to javascript confirm box.

The app runs good. I can select a record and delete it. Then I can select another record. But I cannot delete it. The javascript confirm box runs, but clicking Yes does not delete the record. I wonder why it is okay for 1 time but not the next time.

Any help?

Comment: I think I have some clue. In the first attempt, I clicked the OK button that set input$deleteConfirmChoice to TRUE. When I do it the second time, its value is still true and so there is no change in the value. Thus, the code does not execute. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another approach...

I changed the javascript code passed to session$sendCustomMessage. Clicking the No button returns 0. Clicking the Yes button returns a random number. This I hope will guarantee a different value in two consecutive clicks of the Yes button.

```
    observe({
    if (is.null(input$delete) || input$delete == 0){return()}
    session$sendCustomMessage(
        type = 'jsCode'
        ,list(value = 
            '
            (function() {
                if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
                    return Math.random()*3 + 1;
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }
            })()
            '
        )
    )
})

observeEvent(input$deleteConfirmChoice, {
    if (input$deleteConfirmChoice == "TRUE") {
        x <- input$t_tab_1_rows_selected
        deleteTransaction(x)
        isolate(dFt1$dat <- dFt1$dat[row.names(dFt1$dat) != x, ])
    }
})
```

Any other cleaner solution?

Answer (score 0):

Ok! Finally come to something that is working ...

```
    observeEvent(input$deleteConfirmChoice, {
    if (input$deleteConfirmChoice == "TRUE") {
        x <- input$t_tab_1_rows_selected
        deleteTransaction(x)
        isolate(dFt1$dat <- dFt1$dat[row.names(dFt1$dat) != x, ])
        shinyjs::disable("delete")
        shinyjs::disable("edit")
        session$sendCustomMessage(
            type = 'jsCode'
            ,list(value = '1 != 1;')
        )
    }
})
```

I added another session$sendCustomMessage call that evaluate to be FALSE.

Wonder if there is any better solution?

Comment: Hi, I'm the author of shinyjs, I just wanted to point out that if you're using shinyjs, you shouldn't be using `session$sendCustomMessage` - you should look into `shinyjs::extendShinyjs` to make calling javascript functions simpler